# Request Authorization on App Launch always in Unity Mobile Notification Settings Package

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using the Unity mobile notification package. In the configuration, in the options "Request Authorization on App Launch" and "Register for Push Notification on App Launch" in the iOS section I have it disabled but even so, the request for local notifications in the launch app still appears.

In addition, I am using the following code to make the request:

```
using (var req = new AuthorizationRequest(AuthorizationOption.Alert | AuthorizationOption.Badge | AuthorizationOption.Sound, false))
{
    while (!req.IsFinished)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```